# Probability of average entering range

Tags: calculus, probability, functions

(Skip to TLDR for math)

Let's say I own a fast food restaurant:

As the owner, I want to maximize my profits and increase customer satisfaction. One easy way to do this is to decrease the amount of time each customer waits in line for drive-thru service.

Luckily, my drive-thru has sensors built in that capture when a driver enters and exits the drive-thru. By this, I can determine the drive-thru wait time per customer and the average drive-thru wait time for all customers.

After collecting data for a few months, I set a goal of 60 seconds for the average drive-thru wait time of all customers per month. The formula is simple:

```
averageWaitTime = totalWaitTime / totalCustomers
```

Unfortunately, this month has been very busy. A corporate promotion increased drive-thru traffic for the first week; and although traffic has slowed to normal since the promotion expired, I'm afraid we aren't on track to meet our goal of 60 seconds! Our current average drive-thru wait time is 100 seconds.

Luckily, it is still early in the month. We have already served 500 customers, but we expect to get between 800 to 1000 more customers.

Given this forecast, our average drive-thru wait time for the remainder of the month needs to be below 35 to 40 seconds.

What is the probability that the average drive-thru wait time will go from 100 seconds at 500 customers to 60 seconds (or better) at 1300 and 1500 customers respectively?

TLDR:
what is the probability of:

```
((ac + cx - ad) / x) ≥ y > 0
```

Given:

```
a = 500; c = 60; d = 100;
```

When:

```
800 ≤ x ≤ 1000
```

see: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i0zlrcbdfp

Is it simply area under the curve divided by total area? What would be the total area?

I need a formula.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the variance of the waiting times? Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe without that we can't quite estimate anything. Otherwise, all of the 800 - 1000 customers could have any arbitrarily short or large waiting time. (e.g. we could have all 1000 customers waiting for 1000 seconds, then our mean waiting time would be 700 seconds, but intuitively we know the probability of any customer waiting 1000 seconds is very unlikely!)

Comment: I think that is the part I'm missing. How do I set the upper and lower limits of possible y values? Logically, y must be greater than zero (asymptote). Beyond that, I only know how to set arbitrary limits based on intuition (like you said with the 1000 seconds).  I would prefer to set the limits mathematically. You mentioned variance. Could you elaborate? (Feel free to make up data where needed) I'm looking for a process or perhaps a formula to determine reasonable limits.